# js: attempting to hook fine-uploader into a flask application

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, fine-uploader

Am attempting to hook fine uploader into a Flask endpoint.

Endpoint looks like:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def a_function():
    if request.method == 'POST':
         file = request.files['file']
         {{ do stuff }}
         return render_template('index.html', {{ variables }} )
    return render_template('index.html' )
```

Am attempting to replace a standard form:

```
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

with [fine-uploader](http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-with-jquery-wrapper-demo.html):

```
<div class="centered_div">
   <div id="manual-fine-uploader"> </div>
   <div id="triggerUpload" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">
       <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload now>
   </div>
</div>

...

$(document).ready(function() {
    var manualuploader = $('#manual-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '/'
        },
        autoUpload: false,
        text: {
            uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Files'
        },
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom',
            maxChars: 40,
            responseProperty: 'error',
            enableTooltip: true
        }
    });


    $('#triggerUpload').click(function() {
        manualuploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    });
});
```

but I'm getting some js errors in the console and the endpoint doesn't seem to be managing the `request` correctly:

> POST http://{{ localhost }}:5000/ 400 (BAD REQUEST)
>   jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.js:3903 [FineUploader] Error when attempting
>   to parse xhr response text (SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)
>   jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.js:155 [FineUploader] 'error' is not a valid
>   property on the server response.

and the application errors out with `Upload failed`.

I'm guessing that the issue occurs when I hand the request off in the `endpoint: '/'` line, and am really hoping that I don't have to totally rewrite the `{{ do stuff }}` part of my endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, the code you have listed for your endpoint will never work as-is with Fine Uploader. Your endpoint must return a valid JSON response.  Please see the [server-side examples](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server) and the associated [readme](http://docs.fineuploader.com) for more details.

Second, something does appear to be off as far as your routing is concerned.  Your server is responding with a 400.  You will need to examine your server-side code to determine where the request being rejected and why.  A good first step would be to examine the request in Chrome's network tab, make a note of the endpoint, and then check in the appropriate place in your server-side code.

Comment: sounds like I may need to add something like qqfileupload to my endpoint

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean.

Comment: okay so I got this working with some help from a friend. I needed to 1. replace `file = request.files['file']` with `file = request.files['qqfile']` in my endpoint, 2. have the endpoint return a `json.dumps()` that contained `"success":True` and also leveraged `render_template()` to return a file called `results.html` to a `template` variable, and then 3. make a jquery call on a fresh `<div>` to insert the template variable, rendering the HTML in place.